# What vegetable might be called a Worchester?

Tags: vegetables

When I was young, my parents would put a vegetable in our stir fry that they called a Worchester. I recently found out that this doesn't actually exist so I've been trying to determine what they were feeding me. My girlfriend thinks they might have been a variety of radish.

I unfortunately don't remember the raw vegetable, by when stir fried it was a white disc about the size of a quarter. It had a very uniform size and color, there was no core like you would see in a parsnip. They were a little crunchy, like a raw apple. The taste was quite unique, I can't compare it to anything, but it was a very mild flavour.

Any ideas what they were?

Comment: When you say "worchester" do you mean "worcester", pronounced "wuss-ter", or with the ch pronounced, "wor-chest-er"?

Comment: They pronounced it the second way, with the ch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like sliced water chestnuts to me, especially with the name similarity.

Comment: I vote for this, since it fits the description *and* is a very common ingredient in stir fries.

Comment: Water chestnut ... that fits the description well. Good one.

Comment: I agree... and now I'm wondering whether they really did call it a "worchester" or whether you just mis-heard them saying "water chestnut"!

Answer (score 3):

Intriguing =)

Although it probably is water chestnut, I will still go ahead and try this one ;-)
(can not hurt to have a bit of a choice here, right)

My first thought from the description was **salsify** ( could refer to **black salsify** [*Scorzonera hispanica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorzonera_hispanica) or to **purple salsify** [*Tragopogon porrifolius*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragopogon_porrifolius)  ).

[image]

I mostly know the black one, and it has a quite unique but mild flavor, and it is usually quite evenly thick (like a quarter, could be right).

... and I fond [this article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/home-garden/salsify-a-root-vegetable-that-does-double-duty/2011/12/20/gIQAxL6GaP_story.html) where it says:

> *Traditionally it is called “**oyster plant**”, ...*

which sounds similar to "worcester" ([wuus-tər](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/En-worcester.ogg) see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worcester)).

Even though the texture is usually not so crunchy and it is not normally found in stirfries,
it seems like an almost convincing candidate to me =)
Unless you did't mean to pronounce it like Worcester ... then I would go with water chestnut too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they used radish, they are round and crunch.  Some are the size of a quarter and some smaller. Usually eaten raw, but I suppose they can be used in stir fries.